# Child Process aborted when parent is killed with SIGABRT linux C++

Tags: c++, linux

I have a scenario where a spawned child process is killed when the parent is killed with SIGABRT. In my understanding, the child should continue to run. To mimic the actual code, I created two files presenting child and parent. The parent writes to a pipe and child reads from the read end (STDIN_FILENO).

parent code -> parent.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int pipefd[2];
  std::string message = "test\n";

  if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int pid = fork();

  if (0 == pid) {
    std::cout << "Inside child process\n";

    close(pipefd[1]);

    char *args[] = {"./CHILD", NULL};
    char *envp[] = {NULL};

    if (dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
      std::cout << "dup2 failed\n";
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    execve(args[0], args, envp);
  } else {
    close(pipefd[0]);
    while (1) {
      sleep(1);
      std::cout << "parent writing -> " << message;
      write(pipefd[1], message.c_str(), message.length());
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

child code -> child.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

  std::string str;
  char buf;

  std::cout << "[child] started\n";

  while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) {
    if (buf != '\n')
      str += buf;
    else {
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, str.c_str(), str.length());
      str.clear();
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
    }
  }
  std::cout << "[child] Exiting the application\n";

  return 0;
}
```

if the parent is killed with SIGABRT, the child also receives the same. When the pipe code is removed, the signal is not propagated.

Can you please provide some insight into it?

Comment: What is the reason for the child dying? Could it be that it receives SIGPIPE (for which the default action is to terminate the program.If one end of the pipe gets closed (by the parent dying) and the child is trying to do something on the other end then this can trigger a SIGPIPE.

Comment: the child exits due to SIGABRT too.

Comment: How are you sending SIGABRT to the parent?

Comment: kill -6  `pidof parent` for the programs I posted.

Comment: The child exits because the death of the parent causes the filedescriptors in the parent to be closed, which causes the `read()` in the child to return `0`, causing the loop to exit, at which point the child process outputs `"[child] Exiting the application\n"` and a regular exit due to return from main follows.

Comment: I ran it, did `kill -ABRT $!`, and I got the `"[child] Exiting the application"` message. That wouldn't have happened had the child been killed by `SIGABRT`.

Comment: Same here. I always get the `[child] Exiting the application`.The child never gets killed due to a SIGABRT.

Comment: Indeed! but the difference is in the actual code, the parent is controlled by systemd and exits due to systemd watchdog timeout (which is SIGABRT), in that case, the child also receives SIGABRT.

Comment: @TrilokeshPradhan: Presumably `systemd` is sending the signal to the process **group**.

Comment: @DavisHerring, Yes! I tried with ubuntu systemd, the child process was not crashing. But with ARM platform systemd, the child was also receiving SIGABRT. I don't know where is the configuration to change the behavior?